# Convert Userdata to hex in Wireshark Dissector

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector, lua-userdata

I'm coding Wireshark Dissector lua script now.

How to convert `userdata` to hex string?
I want to get output like this `0102030405060708000a0b0c0d0e0f10`

I can convert hex string using `tostring`.
But it omits long data.
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeX4j.png)

How to convert `userdata` to hex string without omit long data?

```lua
proto = Proto("Test", "My Test Protocol")

function proto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
  print(tostring(buffer()))
  -- "userdata"
  -- print(type(buffer()))
end

tcp_table = DissectorTable.get("tcp.port")
tcp_table:add(1234, proto)
```

## Environment

- Wireshark 3.2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Wireshark, but from a quick look into the manual I get that buffer is [a Tvb](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html#lua_class_ByteArray)

and `buffer()` is equivalent to `buffer:range()` which returns a [TvbRange](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html#lua_class_TvbRange)

There is a Tvb:__tostring function which claims to

> Convert the bytes of a Tvb into a string. This is primarily useful for
>   debugging purposes since the string will be truncated if it is too
>   long.

Printing a TvbRange is truncated to 24 bytes.

I'd try to get a [ByteArray](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Tvb.html#lua_class_ByteArray) from your Tvb and obtain the hex string of that ByteArray using

> 11.8.1.14. `bytearray:tohex([lowercase], [separator])` Obtain a Lua string of the bytes in a ByteArray as hex-ascii, with given separator

So your code might look something like

```
proto = Proto("Test", "My Test Protocol")
function proto.dissector(buffer, pinfo, tree)
  print(buffer:bytes():tohex())
  -- or print(buffer():bytes():tohex())
  -- but I guess if you don't give a range in buffer()
  -- it will be pretty much the same as buffer.
end
```